# How do I add up numbers in Java?

Tags: java

My first Java project is almost finished, but there's only one thing that still bothers me: I need to add up numbers. But I just can't do it. Here's the code:

```
package dieses.programm.wird.getestet;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Zahl eingeben: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String data = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(data);

        int a = 0;

        while (a < 6) {
            System.out.println(a);
            a++;
        }

        if (a > 6) {
            System.out.println("SAFE SPACE");

        } else {
            System.out.println("SAVED");
            System.out.println("GOOD EVENING");
        }
        String s = new String("Alte Noten: ");
        String t = new String("5.5");
        String u = new String("4");
        String v = new String("3");
        String w = new String("2.5");
        String x = new String("6.0");
        String y = new String("5.2");
        String z = new String("4");

        String t1 = t.replaceAll("5.5", "6");
        String u1 = u.replaceAll("4", "4");
        String v1 = v.replaceAll("3", "5");
        String w1 = w.replaceAll("2.5", "3");
        String x1 = x.replaceAll("6.0", "2");
        String y1 = y.replaceAll("5.2", "1.8");
        String z1 = z.replaceAll("4", "4.4");
        System.out.println("Neu: " + s + " " + t1 + " " + u1 + " " + v1 + " " + w1 + " " + x1 + " " + y1 + " " + z1);
        System.out.println("Neue Noten eingeben: ");

        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String data1 = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(data1);
        System.out.println("Zusammengerechnet: t1 + u1 + v1 + w1 + x1 + y1 + z1");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question/Problem?

Comment: Please describe the "But I just can't do it" part.

Comment: What you actually want as output ? What you want to do may be a right requirement but your program looks terribly bad.

Comment: You can't add string literals together and expect your computer to know it is supposed to represent numbers.

Comment: you want `"Zusammengerechnet: "+ (t1 + u1 + v1 + w1 + x1 + y1 + z1)`

Comment: `+` will perform concatenation in case of string instead of addition.

Comment: What is that abomination even supposed to do?! It creates some strings (that should probably be some numeric type, and possibly an array thereof), then creates some *other* strings based on the first, except it replaces *their entire content*, in one case *with the exact same content*. Then the old strings are *never used*. If this is an ‘*almost finished*’ project, then what on earth is it for?!

Answer (score 2):

If it's the final line that's bothering you, Java doesn't interpret your String before printing. You'll need to replace

```
System.out.println("Zusammengerechnet: t1 + u1 + v1 + w1 + x1 + y1 + z1");
```

with

```
double sum = Double.parseDouble(t1) + Double.parseDouble(u1)
    + Double.parseDouble(v1) + Double.parseDouble(w1)
    + Double.parseDouble(x1) + Double.parseDouble(y1)
    + Double.parseDouble(z1);
System.out.println("Zusammengerechnet: " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the numbers together you need to turn them into `int` or `float`. Since you have decimals you should use floats.

Call this on the string to get a float:

```
float t2 = Float.parseFloat(t1);
```

This will turn the string saved at `t1` into a float. You can then add the floats together like:

```
t2 + u2 + v2 + w2 + x2 + y2 + z2
```